# Elliptic Operator Principal Part Inequality (Hints)

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am looking to show the following estimate, for an elliptic PDO $P$ of order $m$ there is $K>0$, $R>0$ such that

$$\bigg|\sum_{|\alpha| \leq m}a_{\alpha}\xi^\alpha \bigg| \geq K|\xi|^m$$

for all $\xi$ with $|\xi| > R$. I have shown the result for the principal part $P_m(\xi)$ and was looking to use that, but I cannot figure out how to do it for the full expression. My main idea was to take

$$f(\xi) := \bigg|\sum_{|\alpha| \leq m}a_{\alpha}\xi^\alpha \bigg| - K|\xi|^m$$

and show that $f$ diverges to positive infinity as $|\xi|$ goes to $\infty$. This would mean that $f$ is bounded below, and also that it would eventually be positive which would give the result. Any hints on how to do any of this?

Comment: The desired estimate holds for the principal part for  **all** $\xi$ by homogeneity. Then show $|\sum_{|\alpha| < m} a_\alpha \xi^\alpha| |\xi|^{-m} \to 0 $ as $|\xi| \to \infty$ and apply the triangle inequality.

Comment: @HansEngler Thank you! I am not sure how to use the triangle inequality to achive a lower bound though, I keep getting useless upper bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an expanded version of the suggestion proposed in the comments by Hans Engler.

Consider any polynomial $Q(\xi) = \sum_{|\alpha| \le m} a_\alpha \xi^\alpha$ and note that $|Q(\xi)| \le \sum_{|\alpha| \le m} |a_\alpha| |\xi|^{|\alpha|}$.  Thus if we set 
$$
b_k = \sum_{|\alpha|=k} |a_\alpha|,
$$
then we can bound
$$
|Q(\xi)| \le \sum_{k=0}^m b_k |\xi|^k.
$$
Now set $\beta = \sum_{k=0}^m b_k$.  If $|\xi| \ge 1$ then 
$$
|Q(\xi)| \le \sum_{k=0}^m b_k |\xi|^k \le \sum_{k=0}^m b_k |\xi|^m = \beta |\xi|^m.
$$
On the other hand, if $|\xi |\le 1$ then 
$$
|Q(\xi)| \le \sum_{k=0}^m b_k |\xi|^k \le \sum_{k=0}^m b_k \cdot 1 = \beta.
$$
Consequently, 
$$
|Q(\xi)| \le \beta(1+|\xi|^m) \text{ for all } \xi \in \mathbb{R}^n.
$$

With this bound in hand we can apply it to your problem.  Write the symbol of your operator as $L = P + Q$ for $P = \sum_{|\alpha|=m} a_\alpha \xi^\alpha$ and $Q = \sum_{|\alpha| \le m-1} a_\alpha \xi^\alpha$.  You have already established that there exists $K >0$ such that
$$
|P(\xi)| \ge K |\xi|^m \text{ for all } \xi.
$$
Thus the triangle inequality tells us that
$$
|L(\xi)| = |P(\xi) + Q(\xi)| \ge |P(\xi)| - |Q(\xi)| \ge K |\xi|^m - \beta(1+|\xi|^{m-1}).
$$
Now we just observe that for $|\xi| > R$ with $R$ sufficiently large we must have that 
$$
\frac{K}{2} |\xi|^m - \beta(1+|\xi|^{m-1}) \ge 0,
$$
and so $|\xi| >R$ implies that
$$
|L(\xi)| \ge \frac{K}{2} |\xi|^m.
$$